# Flattening nested dictionary with possible list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, recursion

I have a nested (dictionaries) and (list of dictionaries) - parentheses for clarity - like the following:

```
{"k": 
  {"hello": "bye",
   "hi": [{"a": "b", "c": "d"}, {"q": "I", "o": "p"}]
  }
}
```

And I want to flatten it into a path like the following:

```
"k/hello/bye/hi/a/b/c/d/q/I/o/p"
```

How can this be done? There may be more layers of dictionaries (even within the ones in a list), so I need a very scalable solution.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: In general dictionaries are not ordered, so that exact string is not guaranteed

Comment: you tagged recursion so you obviously had an idea, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DanielMesejo. They are now...

Comment: @DanielMesejo Let's say we just sort the keys alphabetically to ensure same order. How then?

Comment: @JackArnestad Could one of the leaf elements be a list, for example { 'a':[1, 2, 3] } is allowed?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes, this is a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Recursive Solution

Recursion hardly ever works first run, guess I was lucky:

```
def traverse(struct):
    if isinstance(struct, dict):
        return '/'.join(k+'/'+traverse(v) for k,v in struct.items())
    elif isinstance(struct, list):
        return '/'.join(traverse(v) for v in struct)
    else:
        return struct
```

which gives:

```
'k/hello/bye/hi/a/b/c/d/q/I/o/p'
```

---

**why?**

Each call to the `traverse` function takes a `struct` argument which can be either a dictionary, list, or string.

If it is a dictionary, we join together all the values followed by the result of traversing the corresponding keys. We then return this string.

Similarly, if it a list, we join together the outputs of traversing all the elements and return the result.

Finally, if the `struct` argument is just a string, we return it to our parent.

In every case, each function is unaware of wear it is in the stack of calls, it just knows what its `struct` argument was and returns the correct response for *that*, argument.

This is what is so cool about recursion, you only need to consider one case, and as long as you write it correctly and pass the right things from parent to child, the result just emerges through cooperation.

---

N.B. As `@DanielMeseko` notes in the comments, dictionaries aren't ordered so, for instance, the `hello` an `hi` parts of the final string could "switch places" (along with their children trees).

---

**update**

To make the dictionaries sorted by the alphabetical position of the keys, we just need to use the `sorted()` function on the result from `struct.items()`.

That is to stay: replace `struct.items()` in the above code with:

```
sorted(struct.items())
```

Which will sort alphabetically be default.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to just make it alphabetical order for determining order?